# Writing control File for inserting csv file to Oracle Database

Tags: sql, csv, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have a peice of my csv file to show how its formatted. I just wanted to make sure before I went any further that my data would be uploaded correctly into my Oracle database. Im currently using sqlloader to do this.

```
"SERV TAP ID", "ACCT NUMBER", "MTR ID" , "SERV HOUSE","SERV STREET", "SERV TOWN", "BIL NAME","MTR DATE SET3","BIL PHONE","MTR SIZE","BILL CYCLE","MTR REMOTE ID"

"111111" , "222222222" , "33333333", "444", "Mark AVE", "Monroe", "Dos Equis", "07092008", "" , "0058" , "21", "1480040662"
```

This is what my control file looks like. Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

```
load data
infile GIS.csv
into table Billing
fields terminated by ","
(TAP_ID, ACCT_NUM, MTR_ID, SERV_HOUSE, SERV_STREET, SERV_TOWN, BIL_NAME, MTR_DATE_SET, BIL_PHONE, MTR_SIZE, BILL_CYCLE, MTR_RMT_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right to me. I suggest adding:

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

to skip the quotes around the values and

```
OPTIONS(SKIP=1)
```

to skip the header row.